# How to toggle between hidden elements in an if else statement

Tags: javascript

I have a page that contains 7 hidden tables. Depending on what the user choses from the 2 option fields the table that was assigned to those options should appear. I wrote an if/else statement that takes values from the two option bars and given those values it gives the user the desired table.The problem is that I want to write a condition that makes the "previous table" disappear when the user chooses another option. Right now when the user chooses other options the "second table" appears right below the first one.

```
<select id="certification-select" onchange = "showDiv()">
    <option value="-1">Select</option>
    <option value="1">certified</option>
    <option value="2">not certified</option>
    <option value="3">not certified north</option>
    <option value="4">not certified south</option>
    <option value="5">international</option>
    <option value="6">USA</option>
    <option value="7">Europe</option>
</select>

<select id="location-select"onchange = "showDiv()">
    <option value="-1">Select</option>
    <option value="1">BWZ</option>
    <option value="2">TDI</option>
    <option value="3">USC</option>
    <option value="4">SSC</option>
</select>
```

```
function showDiv() {

    var certification = document.getElementById("certification-select").value;
    var location = document.getElementById("location-select").value;

    if (certification === "1" && location === "1"){
        document.getElementById("one").style.display="block";
    }
    else if (certification === "2" && location === "1"){
        document.getElementById("two").style.display="block";
    }
    else if (certification === "3" && location === "1"){
        document.getElementById("three").style.display="block";
    }
    else if (certification === "4" && location === "1"){
        document.getElementById("four").style.display="block";
    }
    else if (certification === "5" && location === "2"){
        document.getElementById("five").style.display="block";
    }
    else if (certification === "6" && location === "3"){
        document.getElementById("six").style.display="block";
    }
    else if (certification === "7" && location === "4"){
        document.getElementById("seven").style.display="block";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("test").style.display="block";
    }
}
```

Comment: Try hiding all tables at first and then show tables based on condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding all tables at first and then show tables based on condition

```
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById("one").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("two").style.display="none";
    //
    //Write code to hide all tables
    //

    var certification = document.getElementById("certification-select").value;
    var location = document.getElementById("location-select").value;

    if (certification === "1" && location === "1"){
        document.getElementById("one").style.display="block";
    }
    else if (certification === "2" && location === "1"){
        document.getElementById("two").style.display="block";

    }
    else if (certification === "3" && location === "1"){
        document.getElementById("three").style.display="block";
    }
    else if (certification === "4" && location === "1"){
        document.getElementById("four").style.display="block";
    }
    else if (certification === "5" && location === "2"){
        document.getElementById("five").style.display="block";
    }
    else if (certification === "6" && location === "3"){
        document.getElementById("six").style.display="block";
    }
    else if (certification === "7" && location === "4"){
        document.getElementById("seven").style.display="block";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("test").style.display="block";
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable that stores the current visible table, or can add a class to that table and when it changes just remove the class. I would make the table IDs like '**table-11**','**table-12**' and so on. Storing as a class seems cleaner.

```
function showDiv() {

    var certification = document.getElementById("certification-select").value;
    var location = document.getElementById("location-select").value;

    //check of other visible  table

    var tables = document.querySelector('table.visible');
    tables.forEach(function(t){
       //remove the visible class, or you can also add style
        t.classList.remove("visible");
    });
    //add the class to the new table which you want to make visible
    var newTabl = document.getElementById('table-'+certification+location);
    newTabl.classList.add("visible");

}
```

CSS:

```
.visible {
    display: "block"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add a class to the current class which is showing called 'currently showing' Do this inside every one of you if else

```
if (certification === "1" && location === "1"){
   var current = document.getElementById("one");
   current.className += " currentlyShowing";
   current.style.display="block";
}
```

At the top before all your if else's find the current div which is showing and set the display to 'none' and then remove the class.

```
 var current = document.getElementById("currentlyShowing");
 current.style.display="none";
 current.classList.remove("currentlyShowing");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be shortened by using a lookup object :

```js
function showDiv() {
  var options = { 11: 'one',  21: 'two', 31: 'three', 41: 'four', 
                  52: 'five', 63: 'six', 74: 'seven', 99: 'test' } 

  var id = document.getElementById.bind(document);

  for (var key in options)
    id(options[key]).style.display = 'none';

  var key = id("certification-select").value + '' + id("location-select").value;
  id(options[key] || 'test').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<select id="certification-select" onchange = "showDiv()">
    <option value="-1">Select</option>
    <option value="1">certified</option>
    <option value="2">not certified</option>
    <option value="3">not certified north</option>
    <option value="4">not certified south</option>
    <option value="5">international</option>
    <option value="5">USA</option>
    <option value="5">Europe</option>
</select>

<select id="location-select"onchange = "showDiv()">
    <option value="-1">Select</option>
    <option value="1">BWZ</option>
    <option value="2">TDI</option>
    <option value="3">USC</option>
    <option value="4">SSC</option>
</select>

<div style='display: none' id='one'>one</div>
<div style='display: none' id='two'>two</div>
<div style='display: none' id='three'>three</div>
<div style='display: none' id='four'>four</div>
<div style='display: none' id='five'>five</div>
<div style='display: none' id='six'>six</div>
<div style='display: none' id='seven'>seven</div>
<div style='display: none' id='test'>test</div>
```

Comment: I keep getting this error when I use this method  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null "

Comment: @ORCos I added working example. By the way, I just noticed that your if statements check for certification up to 7, but the certification select has values only up to 5.

Comment: you are right.. it was just a type.. edited. thank you :)